# API function is breaking through next.js - ideas on where it is breaking?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, api, next.js

I moved my database to a new server recently and am trying to make sure the changes I made are working properly.

Using next.js api functions, I have changed one specific api call here adding in an error function to use the new database.

```
  const { uid: id } = req.user;

  /**
   * Extract the fields from the body
   */
  const { timezone } = req.body;

  let sql = `SELECT * from settings WHERE user_id ='${id}'`;

  db.query(sql, (err, { rows }) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      return res.end(
        JSON.stringify({
          error: "Internal error.",
          message: "Internal error while getting settings.",
        })
      );
    } else {
      /**
       * Check if the settings exists. If it doesn't exist, create one.
       */
      let finalSql = "";
      if (rows.length !== 0) {
        finalSql = `UPDATE settings SET timezone='${timezone}' WHERE user_id='${id}' ;`;
      } else {
        finalSql = `INSERT INTO settings (user_id, timezone) VALUES `;
        finalSql += `('${id}', '${timezone}');`;
        console.log
      }

      db.query(finalSql, (err, { rows }) => {
        if (!err) return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
        else {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Error while updating settings.",
            error: { message: "Error while updating settings." },
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is leading to a 500 error.

Running locally the error comes out like this,

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `rows` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

So I am wondering - is this to do with faulty SQL code I am using?

Comment: I am not sure but, I think this is issue with query try to check value of id or may be remove that single quote around id